# SDWebImage : ARC semantic issue [UIApplication performSelector:@selector(sharedApplication)]

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, sdwebimage

I have integrated my application project with `SDWebimageView` framework without `Cocoapods`. I found a compiler issues as follows,

No known class method on `class UIApplication`,

> [UIApplication performSelector:@selector(sharedApplication)]

Please note that, I tried build for Simulator SDK , it works fine but gives error for Device SDK.

Please help me on this , Thanks in advance....

Comment: Are you developing an app extension ? This method is unavailable in app extensions.

Comment: No, Actually I am building custom framework which uses SDWebImage. I build it for simulator SDK. it works fine but Device SDK fails

Answer (score 0):

`-performSelector:` is an instance method, calling it as a class (or *static*) method will always cause a compiler error, i.e., `[UIApplication performSelector:@selector(sharedApplication)]`. In other words, an object instance is required to use the `-performSelector:` method.